# Renaming alsa controls

Tags: audio, alsa

Is it possible to rename alsa controls?

My front panel is controlled using "Speaker" and my the back plugs are "PCM". Since this isn't very descriptive I would like to rename them to something more sane (like "front" and "back").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own alsa config file `~/.asoundrc` which overrides `/etc/alsa.conf`. It is possible then to create your own [aliases](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#Aliases) for PCM devices. For example, 'PCM' in mixer is just an alias for the device ie. hw:0,1